# Django not running tests with manage.py test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I have a problem with Django's test. I start this command for running test:

```
$ python manage.py test gastrobook
```

gastrobook is my app, tha comand would be fine for the Django's documentation, in fact it works but don't run nothing test but in tests.py i have written some test! This is that terminal say:

```
$ python manage.py test gastrobook/
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

This is my **tests.py**

> ```
> from django.test import TestCase
> from gastrobook.models import *
> import datetime
> from django.utils import timezone
>
> # Create your tests here.
> def create_recipe(title,desc,procedimento,pub_date,hard,time,person):
>     return Recipe.objects.create(title=title,desc=desc,procedimento=procedimento,pub_date=pub_date,hard=hard,time=time,person=person)
>
> class RecipeTest(TestCase):
>     def setUp(self):
>         create_recipe("cui","dcnjenj","owcjc",timezone.now(),2,"5 ore",2)
>
>     def hard_no_more_than(self):
>         recipe = Recipe.objects.all()
>         for rec in recipe:
>             self.assertIn(rec.hard,range(1,10))
> ```

Comment: What is your Django version ?

Comment: Can you try without the trailing slash (`/`) ? You must specify a Python module (with dots (`.`) as separator) not a directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [unittest documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)

> A testcase is created by subclassing unittest.TestCase. The three individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the letters `test`. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests.

change your test function to `test_hard_no_more_than`, then the test runner whould be able to discover the testcase.

Answer (score 1):

Test methods need to be named starting with "test" for the test runner to find them. So your method should be called "test_hard_no_more_than".